# problems with url in a string

Tags: c#, html

i want to send an email with the SmtpClient and i have a problem with building the body text.

i want to send an email with html text in it.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<body>
 <p> some text </p>
</body>
</html>
```

i want to put this in a string, but i'm having problems with the first line.
i'm trying:

```
StringBuilder mailbody = new StringBuilder();
 mailbody.Append("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\" >");
```

won't work, does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: i think the problem is because of the special characters like \ ...... try to using @ at the begining ex: (@"<!DOCTYPE........

Comment: @user3127022 In the future, please refrain from simply saying "it won't work" - try to add some additional information about *why* you think it's not working.  Are there compile issues?  Is the IDE informing you of an issue?  Are the results unexpected?  There there unexpected side effects of running your code?  Almost every post on the site is because something doesn't work - the *why* is what we're trying to uncover :)

Answer (score 2):

The string contains double-quotes, and you need to escape them. Looks like you tried to do this, but you missed one:

```
StringBuilder mailbody = new StringBuilder();
mailbody.Append("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\" >");
```

Comment: @Silvermind The answer I was referring to got deleted. Someone suggested to do something like this: `'string "with quotes"'` which would work in, say, Perl, but not C#. I removed that footnote from my answer.

Comment: Sorry, good thing it was deleted then ;) I'll remove my comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder mailbody = new StringBuilder();
mailbody.Append("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\" >");
```

You were missing a `\`.

Alternatively because HTML doesn't care you can replace the `"` with `'` in the string (not around it of course, since C# does care).

```
StringBuilder mailbody = new StringBuilder();
mailbody.Append("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd' >");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a verbatim string literal by beginning the string with an @ character. This allows you to split the string into multiple lines if you want, and doesn't require you to escape things like backslashes.

However, you *will* need to escape any double quotes within the string literal by putting two of them next to each other.  So your email statement will look like:

```cs
StringBuilder mailbody = new StringBuilder();
mailbody.Append(@"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN""
""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"">
<html>
<body>
   <p> some text </p>
</body>
</html>");
```